# Zip filesystem performance

Tags: filesystems, zip, binaryfiles

My program creates file system tree from zip file (file system viewer), but the performance are terrible.

To get the real offset of the file I'm reading the "file local header extra data" length.

I tried to get the file real offset ignoring the local file header by taking the extra data from the "central directory extra data" + constant of the local file header, but the files didn't extracted correctly, apparently the "local file header extra data" is different from "central directory extra data" and I notice that the simple case of zip files (store without encryption) - "local file header extra field length" is 0.

So I wrote POC that creates the file streams only from "the central directory" ignoring the "local file header" and the performance improved a lot.

Is there a way to create the file system only from the "central directory" but more robust (also when the "local file header extra field length" is not 0)?